# How change label in <a> tag in email template?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-template

I am trying to add  tag in email template like

```
 <a conversion="false" data-linkto="other" href="%%=v(@URL1)=%%" style="color:#0A4A8E;text-decoration:underline;">%%=v(@Name1)=%%</a>
```

Here problem is already salesforce returning @URL1 value as

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/?hl=en-GB&authuser=1" target="_blank">Test</a>
```

I want like this

```
 <a href="<a href="https://www.google.com/?hl=en-GB&authuser=1" target="_blank">Test</a>" target="_blank">LastName</a>
```

coming like below

```
Test" target="_blank">LastName
```

but i want LastName with link address

Please help me to solve this error

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really unclear, but I will do my best giving it a shot. I assume you want to replace *Test* in the HTML contained in your `@URL1` variable with a proper *LastName* taken from somewhere else.

```ampscript
%%[
var @lastname, @URL1
set @lastname = "Doe"
set @URL1 = "<a href='https://www.google.com/?hl=en-GB&authuser=1' target='_blank'>Test</a>"

if indexOf(@URL1, "'_blank'>") > 0 then
set @fixedURL = Substring(@URL1,1, Add(indexOf(@URL1, "'_blank'>"),8))
endif

]%%
Go to: %%=Concat(@fixedURL,@LastName,"</a>")=%%
```

Be aware, that in this case, where the entire *a href* is contained in an ampscript variable, the link will not be tracked.

Comment: Hi i have value in URL and Name but if condition not satisfying

Comment: @hariP - can you please rephrase you comment, as it is not clear what you mean?

Comment: Above code not working and if indexOf(@URL1, "'_blank'>") > 0 then not satisfying.